# Update all Object Elements of a State Array with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I have a State Array that stores these objects:

```
const hoursArr = [
    { value: 1, label: "hour" , isDisabled:false},
    { value: 2, label: "hours" , isDisabled:false},
    { value: 3, label: "hours" , isDisabled:false},
    { value: 4, label: "hours" , isDisabled:false},
    { value: 5, label: "hours" , isDisabled:false},
    { value: 6, label: "hours" , isDisabled:false}
]
```

Then i assign these objects in the array

```
const [hours,setHours] = useState(hoursArr);
```

What i want to achieve is to iterate the whole array and change the `isDisabled` property from `false` to `true`.

I have done this:

```
let tmpHours = [];
tmpHours=hours.map(item=>item.isDisabled=false);
```

But the `tmpHours` didn't store the entire object but only the boolean value which was `false`.

I thought that `map()` function returned an array but i was wrong it seems. Also i cannot find an answer to my problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let tmpHours = [];
tmpHours=hours.map(item=>({...item, isDisabled: true}));
```

Comment: Thanks! im gonna accept your answer as you was first. But i wanna ask why do we need the parentheses () ? I mean i see that we replace the ```isDisabled``` property there, But i don't get the parentheses.

Comment: The parameter of `map()` should be a callback that returns a new item from the old item. `item => ({..item, isDisabled: true})` is equivalent with `item => {return {...item, isDisabled: true}}`

Comment: I didn't know that one. So instead of ```{return { } }``` you say 
```({...item, isDisabled:true})```. Nice one! Also in your answer you missed a right parentheses ```)```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const hoursArr = [
    { value: 1, label: "hour" , isDisabled:false},
    { value: 2, label: "hours" , isDisabled:false},
    { value: 3, label: "hours" , isDisabled:false},
    { value: 4, label: "hours" , isDisabled:false},
    { value: 5, label: "hours" , isDisabled:false},
    { value: 6, label: "hours" , isDisabled:false}
]

let tmpHours = [];
tmpHours=hoursArr.map(item=>({...item,isDisabled:false}));
console.log(tmpHours)
```

Answer (score 1):

Map method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array. You're missing to create new elements while iterating over the old array to modify the `isDisabled` key value.

You can do this in this way:

```
    const hoursArr = [
        { value: 1, label: "hour" , isDisabled:false},
        { value: 2, label: "hours" , isDisabled:false},
        { value: 3, label: "hours" , isDisabled:false},
        { value: 4, label: "hours" , isDisabled:false},
        { value: 5, label: "hours" , isDisabled:false},
        { value: 6, label: "hours" , isDisabled:false}
    ]
    
    const tmpHours = hoursArr.map((item) => {
        return { ...item, isDisabled: true };
    });
```